# Typescript cannot find module Protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

I am integrating e2e testing in my project. The project uses Typescript (2.6.1).

I have just installed Protractor (5.2.0) but no matter what I do Typescript cannot import anything from the Protractor module.

My tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "amd"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "./spec",
        "./node_modules",
        "./bower_components"
    ]
}
```

My very simple try out test looks like this:

```
import { browser } from "protractor";

describe("test should run", () => {
    it("should navigate to the page", () => {

    });
});
```

I get the following error: `TypeScript error: usermanagement/ts/controllers/RolesController.e2e.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'protractor'.`

Looking at the Protractor installation in my `node_modules` folder I do find a reference to a typings file and the actual typings themselves. However Typescript simply does not 'see' them. Interestingly Typescript has no problem finding typings in the `node_modules/@types` folder.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just discovered if I do `import { protractor } from "../../../node_modules/protractor/built/index";` (e.g. hard reference to specific file) it can import protractor. Obviously this is a less than optimal solution as moving the file would require updating the import path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your tsconfig add:

```
"module": "commonjs"
```

## More

This is the recommended config I mention here as well https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html

Comment: Hi basarat, I got it working. Thank you for your help.